# Javascript Runtime Error IE 11

Tags: javascript, java, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a simpe selects all check boxes button which when selected selects all checkboxes. This has been working in ie7, and ie 8 but when I try to run my code in Ie11 i get a runtime error saying
"JavaScript runtime error: 'SelectAllCheckboxes' is undefined"

Here is my Javascript code

```
      function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk) {

            // Added as ASPX uses SPAN for checkbox
            var oItem = spanChk.children;
            var theBox = (spanChk.type == "checkbox") ? spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];
            xState = theBox.checked;
            var theboxparentname = getparentname(theBox.name)
            elm = theBox.form.elements;
            for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)
                if (elm[i].type == "checkbox" && elm[i].id != theBox.id) {
                    //elm[i].click();
                    if (theboxparentname == getparentname(elm[i].name)) {
                        if (elm[i].checked != xState)
                            elm[i].click();
                        //elm[i].checked=xState;
                    }
                }

        }

            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox id="chkAll" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" AutoPostBack="false"
                                    ToolTip="Select/Deselect All" runat="server" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
```

I have been trying to resolve this by trying to install few hotfixes and receive an error  ("KB2600088 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer".) Any advice or help on this highly appreciated. I get this error for the browsers of version of ie 9 and above

Comment: Is that the *only* error you get, or do you get other errors when the page loads?  (And you don't need `javascript:` for your "onclick" attribute.)

Comment: Your code is not complete, the closing brace of your function is missing

Comment: @Pointy I get couple of other errors for other functions saying that particular function is not defined "JavaScript runtime error: functionname is undefined" (for 3 functions) , and it also the page doesnt load the webform  as it does in ie7 or ie8..and also the panel is very tight on ie11

Comment: @trincot  thanks i corrected that

Comment: Errors during initial page load can cause entire portions of your JavaScript code to be ignored.

Comment: @Pointy yeah i agree with that, by i am not getting any of these errors while I am ie8 i see these errors only on ie9 and above. and the panel is properly alligned in ie8 compared to other versions

Answer (score 0):

the code is incomplete you need to close the brackets. Getting errors for function saying that particular function is not defined "JavaScript runtime error: functionname is undefined" (for 3 functions).

Answer (score 0):

i just hand to change how i declared my functions

```
function something(){
  }
//to
window.something = function()
{
}
```